# Reading file contents line by line using Java

Tags: java

In my java   program I need to  read the contents of file line by line using java.I tried the following code but I am getting this error

```
import acm.program.*;  

import acm.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ReadFile  extends ConsoleProgram{

    private BufferedReader openFileReader(String Prompt){
        BufferedReader rd =null;
        while(rd==null){
            String name=readLine(Prompt);
            try{
            rd=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(name));

        }catch(IOException ex){
            println("cannot open");


        }

    }
        return rd;

    }

public void run(){
    BufferedReader rd = OpenFileReader('File');
    try{
        while(true){
            String line=rd.readLine();
            if(line==null){
                break;
            }
            rd.close();
            catch(IOException ex){
                throw new ErrorException(ex);

            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

I am getting error in this line

```
BufferedReader rd = OpenFileReader('File');
```

The error I am getting is "Invalid character constant".
How should I resolve this?

Comment: `"File"` instead of `'File'`.

Comment: Anything enclosed in `'` is a character constant, and can be only one character long. `File` is a String. You need to enclose in double quotes like `"file"`.

Comment: I changed  but now it is showing  error in more lines.How should I proceed?

Comment: What are the errors? We can't read your mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:  Single quotes are for `char`s, not `String`s.  Changing the single quotes to double will solve your problem, as mentioned in [Yair Nevet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23522829/2030691).

The somewhat longer answer:

A `String` in Java has double quotes, such as `"`.  This can have any number of characters between the opening and closing `"`.

A `char` in Java has single quotes, such as `'`.  This can only have one character between the opening and closing `'`.

The `Invalid character constant` message comes up when you try to assign a `char` value with more than one character between the opening and closing `'`.

Answer (score 2):

You're treating the `File` phrase as if it was a character and not a string:

```
BufferedReader rd = OpenFileReader('File');
```

Change it to:

```
BufferedReader rd = OpenFileReader("File");
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya corrected it .That was the error. I am new to  java programming..

Answer (score -2):

The simple way, is to use org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils

```
FileUtils.readLines(new File("path"));
```

Comment: The question is asking what caused the error, not how to read from a file.

Comment: writing a lot of codes to read a File is a loose of time, the is more cleaner using common library

Comment: Yes, it can be complicated to read from files manually, but it's a good way to practice using Java, and a very common exercise in introductory Java courses.

Comment: So my response has a relationship with the title Question

Comment: i dont read his code, i just read "Reading file contents line by line using Java"

Comment: "I didn't read his code" - That's the problem.  When you answer a question on StackOverflow, you should be answering what the question actually asks.  The titles are very often misleading and/or inaccurate.

Comment: But when some one search in google he will find this page and its good to find the more short answer, not the 60 lines of codes

Comment: Googling gives us [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4716503/2030691), with [this accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4716521/2030691), which are both sufficient.  There are hundreds of duplicate-type questions (such as this one) on StackOverflow.  These people are asking for how to fix their problem, not how to re-design everything they're doing.